# .Net Executable in Azure Function

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, azure-functions, console-application, connection-string

Background: I have a series of console apps that modify a database. They are provided to us. We have access to the code, however, we must make as little as code change as possible. They are console apps that use entity framework 6.
My question is two-fold.

1. What is the best way to deploy these guys as Azure Functions? My current thinking is the Powershell option. This would allow just running the executable with no code change.
2. Depending on the best method to deploy them. How do you get the connection string passed down to the executables configuration?

Answer (score 0):

if the requirements not to refactor the console apps but migrating these.
you may create generic function .csx file and convert console application to an Http service in Azure Functions. the good things of this is to allow specific inputs (and output parameters) of arguments to the console.

you can refer to [functions dotnet migrating console apps](http://the%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/run-console-apps-on-azure-functions/) and enjoy your migration.